# Creating Charts using XSL, XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I should generate HTML document which formats the data from XML below, using XSL.

output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Counts>
  <Dates>
    <Available year="2007">147</Available>
    <Available year="2008">353</Available>
    <Available year="2009">443</Available>
  </Dates>
</Counts>
```

I would like to create bar chart which provides values contained in attribute `year=""` on x-axis //2007,2008,2009, and values contained in element `<Available>` on y-axis//147, 353, 443

It should also be inside of a table. So I tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
          <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8"/>
              <title></title>
          </head>
          <body>
              <table border = "1" width = "100%">
                  <tr> 
                      <th>year</th>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <xsl:for-each select="Counts/Dates/Available">
                              <chart type="bar">
                                  <labels>
                                      <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
                                  </labels>
                                  <data>
                                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                  </data>
                              </chart>
                          </xsl:for-each>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </body>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:**

Because of missunderstanding let me rewrite task. The task could sound something like this: 
Use the output.XML (above) to generate HTML document which formats the data using XSLT. Visualize the document counts for Dates: Example: http://postimg.org/image/qv7co9lul/

I should probably use some plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the desired output. Currently the `<data>` in every chart is empty. But if you just adjust the`<xsl:for-each>` in your current XSLT to

```
<xsl:for-each select="Counts/Dates/Available">
   <chart type="bar">
      <labels>
         <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
      </labels>
      <data>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </data>
   </chart>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the ouput is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th>year</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <chart type="bar">
              <labels>2007</labels>
              <data>147</data>
           </chart>
           <chart type="bar">
              <labels>2008</labels>
              <data>353</data>
           </chart>
           <chart type="bar">
              <labels>2009</labels>
              <data>443</data>
           </chart>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

as `Available` is the current node ( = `.`) in the `xsl:for-each`.
If the desired ouput should look different, please add it to your question.

**Update:** For the added requirement in the comment - to display a chart in HTML it won't work to just have the provided output; instead you would need to include e.g. a jQuery plugin that can display the data as chart and, depending on the plugin, the output has to be generated in a different way to work with the plugin.
You can check e.g. http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=chart for different plugins that will display charts or, as it has not to be jQuery, just google for "HTML chart".
Depending on how the chart should look like, it would also be possible to display a chart using pure HTML and CSS. I've just written a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34esbzjf/) with a simple example markup and CSS how this could look like and added a 4th row to show that the background colors are alternating. In case this kind of bar chart would be sufficient, it can easily be generated by adjusting the current XSLT and no plugin would be needed.

**Update:** For the edited question and the linked image displaying how the chart should look like - I would also suggest to use a plugin, but just to show that it's possible to display a bar chart using HTML and CSS without any plugin I've just adjusted the previous [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lks6bqy6/). I guess the `doc.count` above the chart should display the amount of all docs. Following XSLT generates the ouput that's at the Fiddle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="Dates">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">year</div>
            <div class="docCount">
                <xsl:value-of select="
                               Available[@year='2009']/
                               (. + sum(./preceding-sibling::*))
                               " />
            </div>
            <div class="barchart">
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">500</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">450</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">400</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">350</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">300</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">250</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">200</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">150</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">100</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">50</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="value">0</div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="blockWrapper">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Available">
                        <xsl:variable name="count" select="." />
                        <div class="blockItem">
                            <div class="block">
                                <xsl:attribute name="style" select="
                                     concat('height:', $count div 2, 'px')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="label">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@year" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The height of each bar is half of the `Available` value, and the CSS in the Fiddle sets a height of 25px for every row in the chart (representing 50 documents), so this matches. Though I already suggested to better use a plugin and this approach is only an example for 3 bars (as I also don't know if a chart could consist of more than 3 years), I just wanted to show that it's also possible without using a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for (="."), now I have my data but:

Comment: But, all I get now is 200714720083532009443 - or all of the values in one line...where is my chart? And yes, I can't use these numbers (2007,147,2008,353,2009,443) because my XML is changable (output of some program) and these values could be different next time someone use this program.

Comment: @Prpaa Sorry, then it's a misunderstanding. I just thought your XSLT would be a kind of example and the problem was only to get the data. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again...i taught I can handle it with your infos. But, still I cant get what I want. So I edited my Question, if you know better solution after my edits, please write it down.

Comment: @Prpaa I also think it would be better to use a plugin as you mentioned in your edited question, but just updated my answer with a possible solution.